# Mysql agregation function. Average price and item price

Tags: mysql

Im tring to get in one query how many items price higher than average price and lower.

My query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM item i
WHERE refine = 0 AND item = 5170
GROUP BY id
HAVING price > AVG(price) - STD(price) AND i.price < AVG(price) + STD(price)
```

But i get error *Unknown column 'price' in 'having clause'*

If I'm using AVG and STD functions in SELECT:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(price > AVG(price) - STD(price) AND i.price < AVG(price) + STD(price)) as middle
FROM item i
WHERE refine = 0 AND item = 5170
```

I get error again. How make correct query?

Here link on [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e630c/3)

Comment: Can you provide an example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: Thanks for link to SQLFiddle, nice tool) I've add link to post.

Comment: You can't wrap an aggregate with another aggregate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select count(*) from item as t1 inner join
(
select id,AVG(price) - STD(price) as sum1, AVG(price) + STD(price)  as sum2
from item 
group by id
) as t2
on t1.id=t2.id and t1.price>sum1 and t1.price<sum2
```

Comment: I've add some little modification this query, but this idea work for me. Thank you ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(price > AVG(price)) - STD(price) AND i.price < AVG(price) + STD(price)) as    middle
 FROM item i WHERE refine = 0 AND item = 5170
```

you forgot a ")" -> `SUM(price > AVG(price))`